# Attach file in Postfix filter

Tags: email-attachments, postfix-mta

I am sending mail in Postfix through a filter, where Altermime applies a signature. I'd like to attach an image to the mail, so i can use html (applied by Altermime) that displays the attached image, eg:
    `<img src="cid:pic.jpg" />`

How can I attach a file to the email when using a bash filter?
I have tried piping it with uuenview at the end of the filter to postfix, but it does nothing:
    `uuenview /path/to/pic.jpg | $SENDMAIL -i "$@" <in.$$`

I'm using the filter method as described in: http://www.postfix.org/FILTER_README.html

Answer (score 0):

OK, I realize it is not as easy as piping uuenview to the mail. Emails are broken up with boundaries.

So instead I will work on getting AddAttachFilter working: http://sourceforge.net/projects/addattachfilter/files/

I have had a little bit success so far this morning with it.